# Curve fitting on dataset

Tags: statistics, algebraic-curves, curves, data-analysis

For my master's thesis I'm writing on a specific subject which requires curve fitting. In the first part I fixed everything with 12th degree polynomial fits. But when I derive the data from the place measures, to get the speeds, I get a curve which is hard to fit.

The curve looks like a sinewave, but they go much more pointy on the minimas. Does anyone have any idea about what a good polynomial or other function would be for this kind of curves?

[My Curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PeXiZ.png)

I have tried this already with 12th degree polynomial and with some sorts of sine wave. But maybe it might be a good idea to combine a sine wave and a triangle wave?

EDIT: as people are advising me to get into sine waves, the reason why I don't do this is because I need to fit a lot of datasets which are completely different to this dataset. I made another screenshot to show that sine waves are not a real option for me.

[This dataset would be way harder with a sine wave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlRwP.png)

Comment: What about absolute value of sin?

Comment: 12th degree polynomial becomes hard to interpret. You might consider using a second or third degree polynomial with a change point.

Comment: looks definitely to be the abs of a sinusoid: invert the sign of the second part (or of the first) and look whether a sinusoidal wave fits (or a couple of them with multiple frequencies).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick example of using a change point type method. The model.

\begin{equation}
y(x) = \begin{cases}
\alpha_0 + \alpha_1x + \alpha_2x^2 & x \leq c \\
\beta_0 + \beta_1x + \beta_2x^2 & x > c
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

We have 6 regression parameters, and a break-point parameter $c$. However, we want this model to be continuous at $c$, so we should impose the constraint:
\begin{equation}
\alpha_0 + \alpha_1c + \alpha_2c^2 = \beta_0 + \beta_1c + \beta_2c^2
\end{equation}

Or equivalently, $A \equiv \alpha_0 = \beta_0 + (\beta_1-\alpha_1)c + (\beta_2-\alpha_2)c^2$. So now we have 6 free parameters.

Here's a simulated data set which I will try this out on.
[image]

I'm using R, which is pretty easy to use. If you try to use the $\texttt{nls}$ function, it may complain about identifiability. But we can do this using $\texttt{optim}$

First, I write a simple model function, given a vector of parameters and the $x$ data. Here, par = $[\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2, c]$

```
 model <- function(par, x){
   n <- length(x)
   res <- rep(0,n)
   for(i in 1:n){
      A0 <- par[3] + (par[4]-par[1])*par[6] + (par[5]-par[2])*par[6]^2
      if(x[i] <= par[6]){
         res[i] <- A0 + par[1]*x[i] + par[2]*x[i]^2
      }else{
         res[i] <- par[3] + par[4]*x[i] +par[5]*x[i]^2
      }
   }
   return(res)
 }
```

Then we write a simple function to return the sum of squares. This is the function we want to minimize.

```
 sum_squares <- function(par, x, y){
    ss <- sum((y-model(par,x))^2)
    return(ss)
 }
```

Finally, we minimize the sum of squares with $\texttt{optim}$. Note that you will need to find good initial guesses to converge to the correct solution.

```
 #I found these initial values with a few minutes of guess and check.
 par0 <- c(7,-1,-395,70,-2.3,10)
 sol <- optim(par= par0, fn=sqerror, x=x, y=y)$par
```

When I plot my solution, this is what I get.[image]

You may need to include third order terms for your data. But this certainly avoids having to consider 12th order polynomials! Plus the interpretability of the change-point is a nice feature.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This is a better solution (for me) than having to deal with sine waves. As I'm looking towards a general solution to fit all of my data plots with the same structure of fitted curves. I will edit my first question to show that the sinewaves are not the way to go.

Thanks for the R-code too, but I'm programming in Python for my thesis, I'll do some research to get this into a Python code.

Comment: No problem!. Just so you're aware, I simulated this data to be quadratic. It looks like you will definitely need at least a 3rd order polynomial for a good fit to your data. Also be aware that you will need to have fairly good starting guesses. Also, this can be extended to have multiple break-points, which you may need in some cases.

Comment: I did a curve fit on the 2nd curve in my main post. With the use of 5th order polynomials I can get a very good result. My only issue is how to get these change-point to work in Python.

Comment: It should be the same idea. Write a function for y(x, parameters), and then write a function that returns the sum of squares for a given set of parameter estimates. Then use an optimization package (possibly scipy.otpimize) to find the parameter estimates which minimize the sum of squares.

Comment: I managed to put it into Python code, but it keeps being really inacurrate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43117965/python-curve-fit-with-change-point/43120151#43120151

Do you have any advice

Comment: I see one thing right off the bat. In your $\texttt{if}$ statement for the first function, you have, if $\texttt{x == par[6]}$ when it should be if $\texttt{x >= par[6]}$

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the least_squares function is doing what you want it to. Typically, the function that you would pass to a least_squares function is the model function. But it may need to be rewritten for that to work. The whole point of writing out own sum_squares function, is so that we can treat it as a general optimization problem. I would look into the scipy.optimize package in Python. In particular, there is a minimize function that may do the trick.

Comment: I made some changes to my code and it work now! I use the same function but I place the model function instead of the sum squares and I fixed the x >= par[6] part. I returns a sum of squares of around 0.012, which is okay, but I will do some testing with 3th, 4th and 5th degree polynomials to see if I can get it perfect!

Comment: Excellent! That is good to hear. Please update your post with the results when completed.

Comment: I chose to get back to my original way of fitting the data. As I want to make this process automatic, it is way easier put more change points at default angles, for example every 45°. When I add these curve fits, I get a complete curve fit which is really good, and needs far less computing power! :)